# How to make date range work in my query

Tags: php, jquery

How to make date range work in my query, if I include `AND sales_date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'` it doesn't show anything.

This is my from, to code

```
  From (<?php echo $from; ?>) To (<?php echo $to; ?>)
```

This is my query. I want to make date range work in my query thanks

```
        <?php
          $iq=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from inventory left join product on product.productid=inventory.productid order by inventory_date desc ");
          while($iqrow=mysqli_fetch_array($iq)){


          ?>
            <tr>
              <td class="hidden"></td>
              <td><?php echo date('M d, Y h:i A',strtotime($iqrow['inventory_date'])); ?></td>  
              <td>
              <?php 
                $u=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `user` left join customer on customer.userid=user.userid left join supplier on supplier.userid=user.userid where user.userid='".$iqrow['userid']."'");
                $urow=mysqli_fetch_array($u);
                if($urow['access']==1){
                  echo "Admin";
                }
                elseif($urow['access']==2){
                  echo $urow['customer_name'];
                }
                else{
                  echo $urow['company_name'];
                }
              ?>
              </td>
              <td align="right"><?php echo $iqrow['action']; ?></td>
              <td align="right"><?php echo $iqrow['product_name']; ?></td>
              <td align="right"><?php echo $iqrow['quantity']; ?></td>
            </tr>
          <?php
 }         }
        ?>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery, a Javascript library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use BETWEEN in your query

```
select * from inventory left join product on product.productid=inventory.productid where inventory_date BETWEEN CAST('$startdate' AS DATE) AND CAST('$enddate' AS DATE) order by inventory_date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `inventory_date` field datatype is date or not and also it contain date or not.

Check `$startdate` and `$enddate` is contain date with `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

```
$sql = "select * from inventory
            left join product on product.productid=inventory.productid
            where
            date(inventory_date) BETWEEN ".$startdate." AND ".$enddate." order by inventory_date desc";
```